# Static and non-static method in one class with the same name JAVA

Tags: java, static

I know it is impossible to override a method in one class. But is there a way to use a non-static method as static? For example I have a method which is adding numbers. I want this method to be usefull with an object and also without it. Is it possible to do something like that without creating another method?

EDIT:
What I mean is, if I make a method static I will need it to take arguments, and if I create an object with variables already set it will be very uncomfortable to call function on my object with same arguments again.

```
public class Test {

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public Test(int a,int b,int c)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public static String count(int a1,int b1, int c1)
    {        
        String solution;
        solution = Integer.toString(a1+b1+c1);
        return solution;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println(Test.count(1,2,3));
       Test t1 = new Test(1,2,3);
       t1.count();
    }

}
```

I know the code is incorrect but i wanted to show what I want to do.

Comment: Why not simply call it statically in the object ?

Comment: What have your tried? Please post your code.

Comment: Your best bet is to have the method as static, so you can call them in a static or non-static situation, assuming the method doesn't need to manipulate instance variables (which wouldn't make sense). We could help you more if you provide us more details.

Comment: I'm surprised by people downvoting this question. He didn't understand the correct use of static methods, but it's a reasonable question.

Comment: I have edited my post with explanations on what I want to do maybe it will help to understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want this method to be usefull with an object and also without it.
>   Is it possible to do something like that without creating another
>   method?

You will have to create another method, but you can make the non-static method call the static method, so that you do not duplicate the code and if you want to change the logic in the future you only need to do it in one place.

```
public class Test {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public Test(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String count() {
        return count(a, b, c);
    }

    public static String count(int a1, int b1, int c1) {
        String solution;
        solution = Integer.toString(a1 + b1 + c1);
        return solution;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test.count(1, 2, 3));
        Test t1 = new Test(1, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(t1.count());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this is exactly what I wanted to do. I just didn't know that having both of them, this:`public String count()` 
and this 
`public static String count(int a1, int b1, int c1)`
 is legal

Answer (score 6):

> But is there a way to use a non-static method as static?

No, it's not possible.

If you need this method to be used in static and non-static context, then make it `static`. The opposite *configuration*, however, is not possible.

Comment: How should I use it in static context when my static method needs arguments to work? Some functionality in Java that will copy object variables into method?

Comment: I don't understand how this is an answer to the question. If you only have a static method, even if you call it from an instance, it doesn't really run in a non-static context (aka you cannot access the object fields).

Answer (score 0):

Make it static, then it can be used with object and without it.

```
 public class MyTest() {
     public static int add() {
         System.out.println("hello");
     }
 }

MyTest.add(); //prints hello

MyTest myobject = new MyTest();
myobject.add(); //prints hello
```

Comment: I downvoted because this was already suggested in comments, and in answer. Plus, you did not even succeed to properly format your code.

Comment: Also downvote, it does not answer his question. The answer is: "no". You don't mention it.

Comment: @darijan i answered it to solve OPs probelem, not for quiz like yes or no

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard if you can see time difference, there was no answer or comments when i started writing.