# Should I make a method that's both static and non-static?

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns, persistence

When I have a method that uses properties of the containing class, but I also need to use that method without having an object of that class, is it OK to make a static overload of that method?

A simple example:

```
public class Parent {
    public string LastName;

    //... constructor etc.

    public Child[] GetChildren() {
        // Retrieve Children (from DB) by LastName
        return DB.GetChildren(LastName);        
    }
}
```

In this example the method `GetChildren` uses a property of the containing class (`Parent.LastName`) to query the database.

This works fine when I have a `Parent` object, but what if I only have a `LastName`? My solution would be to create a static overload that takes a `lastName` as an argument:

```
public Child[] GetChildren() {
    return GetChildren(LastName);       
}

public static Child[] GetChildren(string lastName) {
    // Retrieve Children (from DB) by LastName
    return DB.GetChildren(lastName);
}
```

But is this the right way to do it? I can imagine that this can become very messy when there are a lot of "duplicate" methods in the same class. What's the best way to structure this code without everything becoming cluttered?

**Edit:** I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788841/static-and-non-static-method-in-one-class-with-the-same-name-java) question, which overlaps with mine, but I'm curious how code should be structured when there are *many* methods where this is the case (instead of just one or two). Should code be split up, for example?

Comment: A static method should never make use of the properties in a class. Static methods should be [*pure* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395311/difference-between-pure-and-impure-function).

Comment: I would stick with static method and remove instance method. no matter you have `Parent` or not. you have to send lastname

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary But should it then still be in the `Parent` class, if it does not use any of the Parents properties?

Comment: Why not just create a new `Parent` object with the required properties set and use the non-static method instead of using a static method?

Comment: @Reddy Because this would require gathering all properties of the Parent, which sometimes need to come from a database. So it is possible, but due to performance it's not ideal

Comment: @Duncan Just instantiate the object with the required properties, in this case the `lastName`,  not all...